# Ошибка при сборке проекта с модулями зависящими друг от друга

Tags: java, maven, intelij

В проекте есть два независимых модуля под названиями webapp и utils.
Разработка ведется с помощью intelijIdea и maven.

Возникла необходимость сделать utils зависимым от webapp чтобы переиспользовать код, но возникает ошибка во время сборки. Причем maven отправляется за зависимостью в нексус вместо того, чтобы взять ее в соседней папке.

На какие настройки нужно обратить внимание?

Структура проекта такая - есть корневой pom.xml где перечислены модули, причем webapp собирается раньше чем utils, далее идут вложенные независимые модули webapp и utils.

Пробовал добавить в utils pom.xml зависимость на нужный модуль по аналогии

org.openmrs.module
  idgen
  2.0.1
  jar
  provided

Если не использовать ничего из модуля webapp, то компилируется, но, если начать использовать классы из модуля webapp, то возникает ошибка компиляции со словами, что невозможно найти нужные классы.

Comment: Может, в версиях зависимостей что-то не так?

Comment: @Roberto  чтобы использовать webapp  как зависимость, нужно сначала создать артефакт в локальном или удаленном репо